# Assigning values to an unhashable list in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a column in dataframe which contains lists. As you can see from the below image.

[image]

I want to know how can I extract all the words from this column without any duplicate words and need to iterate over the list of unique words from `0` to `len(uniquewordlist)` and assign a value to each word based on which iteration I'm in.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Instead of an image can you post a sample of your data and expected output?

Comment: Are you trying to label each word? You might want to look at the `sklearn` package and its labelers.

Comment: @Vic13 Look at my answer, and let me know if that's sort of what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is sort of how your data is!

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[['kubernetes', 'client', 'bootstrapping', 'ponda']], [['micro', 'insu']], [['motor', 'upi']],[['secure', 'app', 'installation']],[['health', 'insu', 'express', 'credit', 'customer']],[['secure', 'app', 'installation']],[['aap', 'insta']],[['loan', 'house', 'loan', 'customers']]])

df.columns = ['ingredients']

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                 ingredients
0  [kubernetes, client, bootstrapping, ponda]
1                               [micro, insu]
2                                [motor, upi]
3                 [secure, app, installation]
4   [health, insu, express, credit, customer]
5                 [secure, app, installation]
6                                [aap, insta]
7              [loan, house, loan, customers]
```

Here is the code to bring out a list of unique words.

```
for i in df.index:

    df.at[i, 'string'] = " ".join(item for item in df.at[i, 'ingredients'])

df.drop(['ingredients'], axis = 1, inplace = True)

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

countvec = CountVectorizer()

counts = countvec.fit_transform(df['string'])

vocab = pd.DataFrame(counts.toarray())
vocab.columns = countvec.get_feature_names()

print(list(vocab.columns))
```

Gives

```
['aap', 'app', 'bootstrapping', 'client', 'credit', 'customer', 'customers', 'express', 'health', 'house', 'insta', 'installation', 'insu', 'kubernetes', 'loan', 'micro', 'motor', 'ponda', 'secure', 'upi']
```

You now have a list of your unique vocabulary. If you can give further context as to how you want to assign values, I can continue this answer.

Extended answer:

```
wordlist = list(vocab.columns)


worddict = {}

for i in range(0, len(wordlist)):

    worddict[wordlist[i]] = i

print(worddict)
```

Comment: Yes, it's working but my data is very large and due to this anaconda is not responding.

Comment: Now, I want to assign a unique numeric value to all the unique words.

Comment: @Vic13 How do you want to assign them, because I can't seem to understand why and on what basis you're going to assign values to them, if you tell me, I will extend my code.

Comment: I am going to use those values to predict something. I need some values out of these words so that I can use it to train my model.

Comment: @Vic13 Would it be okay, if you had something like `{'word1': somevalue, 'word2': anothervalue..}`

Comment: Yes, it would be okay.

Comment: @Vic13 I need you to be VERY specific! What value are you planning to assign inside?

Comment: values starting from 0 till n. Where n is the number of words in the list.

Comment: @Vic13 I've added my extended code! Let me know if it works! If you're happy, make sure to upvote and tick it.

Comment: @Vic13 You're very welcome, please keep in mind that if you can communicate VERY clearly exactly what you want, like you did right now in the comments, and posted a sample DataFrame, you would've gotten your solution in under 2 mins.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enumerate` and `itertools.chain` within a dictionary comprehension. `set` ensures mappings are unique.

Data from @Abhishek.

```
from itertools import chain

res = {v: k for k, v in enumerate(set(chain.from_iterable(df['ingredients'])))}

print(res)

{'aap': 15,
 'app': 3,
 'bootstrapping': 1,
 ...
 'ponda': 0,
 'secure': 17,
 'upi': 5}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain @jpp's answer with a different one liner (works for dataframes as well):

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
s = pd.Series([['apple', 'orange', 'raspberry'],
               ['apple', 'cucumber', 'strawberry', 'orange']])
s.apply(Counter).sum()

Counter({'apple': 2,
     'cucumber': 1,
     'orange': 2,
     'raspberry': 1,
     'strawberry': 1})
```

If you use

```
list(s.apply(Counter).sum().keys())
```

you get exactly @Abhishek's answer, which is in my opinion more readable. Applying `set` won't work, since + is not defined for sets